# Unsubscribe Confirmation Page Shows Too Much Information

Tags: civimail

When users click to unsubscribe from our newsletter, to confirm their unsubscribe they are taken to a page in CiviCRM that shows them all of the groups that the email was sent to.

Is there anyway to change it so that these groups are not visible to them?

Answer (score 2):

Since 5.32 there are new fields in the Group Setting, so as well as the original Title and Description, there are now Public Title and Public Description fields, which, if used, will show to the public when unsubscribing from a mailing, or using the Subscribe page

Answer (score 1):

Write an extension and use hook_civicrm_buildForm( $formName, &$form ) 
where you can change the values for the specify page

please use this link for reference for more details 
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC43/hook_civicrm_buildForm